Can I ignore a property in EqualsVerifier?
I have a class like this:
class Thing(val name: String) {
  internal var complexObject: ComplexType? = null
  override fun equals(other: Any?): Boolean {
    return other is Thing && name == other.name
  }
}

And a test like this:
import nl.jqno.equalsverifier.EqualsVerifier
import org.junit.Test

class ThingTest {
    @Test
    fun `test equals and hashCode`() {
        EqualsVerifier.forClass(Thing::class.java)
            .verify()
    }
}

Now I want to completely ignore complexObject in EqualsVerifier. It's a type it cannot instantiate, and it asks me to provide a prefab object (withPrefabValues) for it. This would work, but my Thing is used in a lot of places and other people write a lot of tests for classes that contain a Thing, and the complexObject should be none of their concern. Comparisons of this object are not necessary for these downstream tests to work.
Can I somehow mark complexObject as always being null for the purposes of EqualsVerifier?
Ideally without touching all tests which verify objects which transitively use a Thing, but if it's only possible test by test, then this would already be an improvement over having to pass a prefab object every time (because withPrefabValues needs at least one real object that is not null).

Do you need complexObject to actually be part of the data class's equals method in the first place? It can be removed there, then you wouldn't need to do anything special in your tests. It will affect your regular code, though. Would that be an option?

Please don't make substantial changes to the question that invalidate already given answers. Write a new question instead.

I don't see how it invalidates your answer. The idea was good, it just doesn't work. The result is exactly the same for data classes and non-data classes -- the problem is not in tests for THIS class, the problem is in tests which use an instance of this class. They don't care if it is a data class, or how my equals function works.

Creator of EqualsVerifier here.
Unfortunately, what you ask for isn't possible. Even for fields that aren't used directly by equals and hashCode, EqualsVerifier still wants to assign values to them, to prevent potential NullPointerExceptions in unrelated parts of the code that EqualsVerifier might touch.
As a workaround, perhaps you can use a mocking framework to create mocks of ComplexType, and feed those to withPrefabValues. (Also, as @Leviathan suggests, perhaps some re-architecting will also help. Does complex logic belong in a type that also needs to have an equals method? Maybe you can extract an interface for ComplexType? That might make other tests easier to do, too.)

Thanks. The concrete usecase is: I have a Parent which has a list of Children and I want to have a pointer back to the parent in each Child -- a circular reference. What you suggests works, I can use prefab values. When I use WeakReference to refer to the parent, I can even pass two WeakReference(null) to withPrefabValues. But there are many tests in my codebase which use a Parent object, or an object that contains a Parent, etc. And I also don't want every future developer who writes an equals test for a new class containing Parent to stumble over that issue.

So, I guess I have to redesign. It would be great to have an annotation for the nullable circular fields that tells EqualsVerifier to just assume null there.

If you're trying to test multiple Children with a single Parent class, you could also consider using a configuration object. See https://jqno.nl/equalsverifier/manual/several-classes-at-once/ (near the end)

I don't see why you even want to test a data class with EqualsVerifier in the first place. After all the method implementations that are tested (equals, hashCode) are auto-generated by the compiler. This is nothing you or your tests should concern themselves with.
In the case you want to actually have two Thing instances compare as equal while ignoring the complexType property you can remove that property from the equals/hashCode generation. As the documentation states only the properties declared in the primary constructor are included, so something like this would work:
data class Thing(
    val name: String,
) {
    var complexObject: ComplexType? = null
        private set

    constructor(name: String, complexObject: ComplexType?) : this(name) {
        this.complexObject = complexObject
    }
}

Thing has still a compatible API surface, so making this change shouldn't break any existing code. It will change its behavior though: Comparing two objects with the same name but different complexObject would now register as equal. Make sure this either can never happen (this is something you should test!) or won't have any undesirable impact.

Unfortunately EqualsVerifier still needs to be able to construct the object even if it's not part of the equals method and the primary constructor. So I still get java.lang.AssertionError: EqualsVerifier found a problem in class com.example.SomeUnrelatedTypeThatContainsThing. -> Recursive datastructure..

The takeaway from this answer should be to not even use EqualsVerifier for data classes in the first place.

It's not a data class anymore. I changed the class to more or less the thing you proposed.

Then the entire premise changed and this answer doesn't apply anymore. equals and hashCode won't be generated automatically so you need to provide your own implementation. This allows an entirely different approach to your problem. You should ask a new question for that. It's structurally diifferent from what you initially asked.

It will still be the same question -- how do I get EqualsVerifier to not try to construct an instance of a specific member and instead assume null.
